# Graphql/Prisma, autorization with or without passport?

Tags: node.js, authentication, authorization, graphql, prisma

I'm creating an API with graphql and Prisma and have been following this tutorial for tips and trix: https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/6-authentication/. When they reached authorization they opted not to use middleware like passport.js but instead wrote their own logic as you can see in the link. I'm simply wondering why and if this solution is lacking in a security perspective?

Answer (score 0):

passport is really handy if you want to setup facebook, twitter and google auth. For simple password login just write your own functionality, it is simpel todo and gives you full control.